# How do I escape characters when running COPY command on command line?

Tags: postgresql, psql, command-line

I'm using Postgres 14 on CentOS 7.  I would like to run a copy command from a bash script.  I first tried running the command on the command line

```
$ PGPASSWORD=$DB_PASS psql -U $DB_USER -d $DB_NAME -c 'COPY myapp_currencyprice to STDOUT WITH (DELIMITER ",", FORMAT CSV, HEADER) \g /tmp/prices.csv'
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "\"
LINE 1: ...o STDOUT WITH (DELIMITER ",", FORMAT CSV, HEADER) \g /tmp/pr...
```

What's the right way to escape the delimiter?  I've tried changing my single and double quotes but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-c` option to psql does not support mixtures of SQL commands and metacommands.  And since that is the only way `\g` can sensibly be used, that means `\g` is not supported in `-c`

There are no shortage of other options though.

```
psql -c 'COPY myapp_currencyprice to STDOUT WITH (DELIMITER ",", FORMAT CSV, HEADER)' > /tmp/prices.csv

psql -c '\COPY myapp_currencyprice to /tmp/prices.csv WITH (DELIMITER ",", FORMAT CSV, HEADER)'

psql -f <(echo 'COPY myapp_currencyprice to STDOUT WITH (DELIMITER ",", FORMAT CSV, HEADER) \g /tmp/prices.csv')

psql <<END
COPY myapp_currencyprice to STDOUT WITH (DELIMITER ",", FORMAT CSV, HEADER) \g /tmp/prices.csv
END
```